# CakePHP 3 - Where is custom datasource?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a large number of CakePHP 2 web applications, many of them use remote data over the custom DataSource. I'm reading the documentation of CakePHP 3, but I can not find instructions for creating custom datesource.

My next project also requires a custom DataSource (ArangoDB), so I planned to build it with the new version of CakePHP.

Please do specify where and how to build a DataSource in CakePHP 3.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the code of any existing database driver and see how it is built? There is nothing in the book yet about how to create your own datasource.

ArangoDB seems to be yet another NoSQL DB, so take a look at [how this Elastic Search datasource](https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search) is done. By a quick look I think you can use it as a base for your implemention, they *seem* to be similar.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem so I decided to write my own models in CakePHP 3.x. If you want you can use it from [here](https://github.com/raulsi/CakePHP-ArangoDb). hope you like it.