# Custom datasource for cakephp3 to be work with mssql_connect?

Tags: datasource, cakephp-3.0

I could not find any document regarding the custom datasource like the earlier versions of cakephp? Anybody know how to create a custom datsource? (Needs to work with mssql_connect). Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3 - Where is custom datasource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411494/cakephp-3-where-is-custom-datasource)

Comment: What kind of ancient SQL server are you running that you cannot use PDO, and therefore the SQL Server driver that ships with CakePHP? The Mssql extension isn't even available anymore for Windows as of PHP 5.3.

Comment: Thanks ndm but, I'm just looking to connect from linux to SQL server, where sqlserv ain't support.

Comment: You could use the linux ODBC driver that microsoft offers and implement a simple driver class to use it.